# Multi-output losses keras/tensorflow do not behave as expected. Target #2 MAE loss is huge and >1 despite sigmoid activation and 0-1 scaled labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

> SOLVED: see comment by Marco Cerliani. tl;dr Each output must be
> passed to the model as a separate array.

I have a neural network with two different targets to estimate:

**Target #1** is 0-infinity, final single node dense layer uses 'linear' activation function.

**Target #2** is 0-1 scaled, final single node dense layer uses uses a 'sigmoid' activation function.

Both outputs are using MAE loss, however MAE for Target #2 is almost as high as for Target #1. As Target #2 is 0-1 and the sigmoid can only give a 0-1 output, I would expect that the loss for Target #2 should not be able to be >1.

Indeed, when I only estimate Target #2 in a single output model I always get a loss <1. The problem arises only when using multiple-outputs.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
mae_loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
rmse_metric = tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, CHANNELS))
model = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_tensor=inputs, 
weights='imagenet')

# Freeze the pretrained weights if needed
model.trainable = True

# Rebuild top
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model.output)
x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

top_dropout_rate = 0.0 # adjustable dropout
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(top_dropout_rate, name='top_dropout')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name='dense_top_1')(x)

output_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', name='output_1')(x)
output_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output_2')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, [output_1, output_2], 
name='VGG16_modified')
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=mae_loss, metrics=rmse_metric)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=epochs, validation_data=[X_val, y_val], verbose=1)
```

I have also tried to compile explicitly with two separate losses:

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=[mae_loss, mae_loss], metrics=[rmse_metric, rmse_metric])
```

Example targets:

```
[[2.05e+02 7.45e-01]
 [1.33e+02 1.46e-01]
 [8.00e+01 2.77e-01]
 [8.30e+01 4.29e-01]
 [9.80e+01 1.50e-01]
 [6.10e+01 3.10e-01]
 [1.00e+02 4.09e-01]
 [2.20e+02 9.17e-01]
 [1.20e+02 1.52e-01]]
```

Terminal outputs (partly cropped, but you get the idea (it shouldn't be possible for loss #2 to be >76 given the sigmoid function and above targets):

[image]

TensorFlow v.2.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model expects 2 targets (`output_1` and `output_2`), while you are using only `y_train` as a target during `model.fit`.

You should fit your model passing two separated target in this way:

```
model.fit(X_train, [y_train[:,[0]],y_train[:,[1]]], ...)
```